# using datagridview values in a string for printing

Tags: c#, ms-access, printing

I created a POS system, in the sales form, user adds products to datagridview and then it gets saved to the database.

I'm currently making the save button print the receipt as well, but I want to add this datagridview items to the receipt but apparently I did it wrong

that's the printing strings

```
string welcome = "Thank You For Visiting Dulabk";
string InvoiceNo = txtInvoiceNo.Text;
string InvoiceDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToLongDateString();
string list = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;

Bitmap bitm = new Bitmap(list.Length * 30, 90);

            using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitm))
```

so probably the datagridview values should be written different I presume

I use a for statement for the database input

```
for (int i = 0; i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++ )
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=TS-POS.accdb");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Sales (InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate, Pname, Pprice, Bcode, Staff) VALUES ('" + txtInvoiceNo.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "', '" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "', '" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "', '" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "', '" + lblUser.Text + "')", conn);
           // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staff", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = lblUser.Text;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            conn.Close();

        }
```

Ok Last Update, now printing all information but have problem with all printing in the same line in the code below  I tried using pointf but didn't help

```
 private void printready()
        {


            stri

ng welcome = "Thank You For Visiting Dulabk";
            string InvoiceNo = txtInvoiceNo.Text;
            string InvoiceDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToLongDateString();
            Bitmap bitm = new Bitmap(welcome.Length * 30, 90);

            using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitm))
            {


                Font newfont = new Font("Arial Black", 8);
                Font newfont2 = new Font("Arial Black", 10);
                PointF point = new PointF(40f, 2f);
                SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush white = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                graphic.FillRectangle(white, 0, 0, bitm.Width, bitm.Height);
                graphic.DrawString("" + InvoiceNo + "", newfont2, black, point);
                PointF pointPrice = new PointF(15f, 45f);
                graphic.DrawString("" + InvoiceDate + "", newfont2, black, pointPrice);
                PointF pointPname = new PointF(10f, 65f); 
                PointF pointBar = new PointF(10f, 65f);
            graphic.DrawString("" + welcome + "", newfont2, black, pointBar);
            PointF pointList = new PointF(10f, 65f); 

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    graphic.DrawString("  " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value +"" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value +"" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value +"" , new Font("Arial Bold", 11),
                             new SolidBrush(Color.Black), pointList);
                                    }

                PointF pointItemEnd = new PointF(10f, 65f);
                graphic.DrawString(" ---------- ", newfont2, black, pointItemEnd);

            }


            using (MemoryStream Mmst = new MemoryStream())
            {


                bitm.Save("ms", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                pictureBox1.Image = bitm;
                pictureBox1.Width = bitm.Width;
                pictureBox1.Height = bitm.Height;


            }
```

Comment: Is this your complete code? I can't see you writing anything to the bitmap at all.

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: Is this what you want? [Control.DrawToBitmap()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx)

Comment: I edited the question with the try I did

Comment: All your data text is printing in the same spot.  You have to increment the pointPname position.  Your unused "ii" variable will always be "2".

Comment: so this is wrong?                 PointF pointPname = new PointF(10f, 65f);

Comment: Ok sorry, got it

Comment: Ok Lars, I'm totally lost now, it did as you said it would, I removed the unused ii, but don't know what should I do? I used pointf but still not good

Comment: Think this through.  Your are looping through your rows, and presumably, you want to print each item on a separate line in your graphic.  But you print always in the same spot.  Somewhere in that loop, you need to increment your "Y" position to be x-amount of pixels below the previous row.

Comment: so something like that

'                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    

                    graphic.DrawString(" " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value +"  " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value +"  " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value +"" , new Font("Arial Bold", 11),
                             new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
                    Offset = Offset + 20;
                }'